# SQL queries: expects more than one results, but only one returns

Tags: sql

I have a problem with the number of results I get after running this query:

```
SELECT g.genre_name, 
       count(distinct(d.director_id))
  FROM genre g, 
       director d, 
       movie m
 WHERE g.genre_id=m.genre_id 
       AND m.director_id=d.director_id;
```

The tables and their keys are:

1. `genre(genre_id, genre_name)`
2. `movie(genre_id, director_id)`
3. `director(director_id)`

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the [`GROUP BY`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php)

```
  SELECT g.genre_name, 
         count(distinct(d.director_id))
    FROM genre g, 
         director d, 
         movie m
   WHERE g.genre_id=m.genre_id 
         AND m.director_id=d.director_id
GROUP BY g.genre_name;
```